# Reassigning the AltGr key to the Windows Key in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

How do I reassign the AltGr key (or any other key for that matter) to the Windows Key in Windows 7?

Is there a native setting to do that? Or is a third-party solution the only possible way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler solution is to re-map the keys, and there's a quick and easy way to do that.

[Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 7 / XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html)  to reassign the keys in this way

> SharpKeys is a Registry hack that is used to make certain keys on a keyboard act like other keys. For example, if you accidentally hit Caps Lock often, you could use this utility to map Caps Lock to a Shift key or even turn it off completely. This official release includes support for up to 104 mappings, an extensive list of available keys, and a "Type Key" option to help when managing mappings. As it relies on internal support within Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, or Windows Vista you must be running one of these OS's for this Registry hack to work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would do the job. (Though I don't use it personally, maybe someone else could add more details)

Answer (score 1):

[KewyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/KeyTweak_install.exe) helped as well.