# How can I remap a keyboard key?

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping

One of my laptop's keys has fallen off. Is there any way I can remap another key to serve as that key?  I'll 'sacrifice' the other key because I never use it.

Comment: Scroll lock: *Why are you looking at me?*

Comment: This question covers **permanently** remapping keys. Most answers are based on a registry edit requiring a reboot. For ways to remap keys **without a restart**, **swapping** keys with each other, or swapping for **specific applications**, see this question: [Remapping keyboard keys for specific applications](http://superuser.com/questions/88238/remapping-keyboard-keys-for-specific-applications)

Comment: @harrymc the vlaurie.com link is dead (now hosted by ParkLogic)

Comment: @johnvkumpf: There are heaps of such articles. Most dead links can still be found on the Wayback Machine. For this one see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170503162042/http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm).

Comment: SharpKeys (free download from authoritative source): https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is a good article from Howtogeek about using a utility called [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys):

> ##Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 10, 8, 7, or Vista
> If you are tired of the way certain keys on your system work, such as the Caps Lock key, you can re-map them to function as a different key by [using a registry hack](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/). But there should be an easier way, right?
>
> This is where SharpKeys comes into the picture: It’s a small utility that will let you easily map one key to another key easily, or even turn the key off, without having to enter the registry at all.
>
> For instance, I used the key mapping to just turn off my Caps Lock key, since I never use it.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/image195.png))</sub>

> You can click the Add button to bring up the Add New Key Mapping dialog, where you can either select the keys to map from the lists, or just click the Type Key button and press the key manually (which I find much more intuitive)
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/image196.png))</sub>

> Once you are done, click the Write to Registry button and you’ll be told to log off or reboot for the changes to take effect.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/image197.png))</sub>

> If you want all the technical details on how the registry keys work, you can read about [how to map keys using registry hacks](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/).

[Link for reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

Comment: For simple remapping this is the way to go, no need to write a full blown autohotkey script. I swear by AHK don't get me wrong, but thats more for keyboard **combinations** rather than simple remapping.

Comment: Very easy to use - would be more lovely to be able to toggle the keys (enable/disable it) without deleting anything

Comment: Will this allow me to swap the Fn and Ctrl key in Windows on a Macbook Pro Retina running Bootcamp? Thanks.

Comment: Do I have to run the app all the time, or is the change permanent?

Comment: The HowToGeek registry hack link above is perfect for doing this without software -- but the scancode link in said article is dead. Here's a live (as of today) one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: I am using two different USB keyboards the same time, working multilingual. One of my keyboards has a disturbing layout for INS, END, DEL, ... that I wanted to change. Needing to reboot everytime I change the keyboard is not a solution. Then probably Autohotkey is. Need a simple on-off-switch. Or I just get used to SHIFT + NumKeys...

Comment: It seems my custom mapping was reset after a Windows update. Did anyone had this issues?

Comment: Seems like this doesnt support remapping to Alt Gr.

Comment: Thanks for this lovely solution!
PowerToys (its "Keyboard Mapper") can also remap a key.
But PowerToys comes with an auto-update notifier that cannot be disabled.
It was driving me nuts. With this solution, I get the peace of mind that I need.
Colonel Panic, once the registry has been changed (and you logout/login),
it's permanent. As opposed to PowerToys, which has to run all the time.
The
[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134)
might work as well, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 14):

Using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) here without problems. For switching modifier keys I would suggest a registry hack or an application that changes the registry for you, do not use a pure software remap like AutoHotkey as those solutions don't work for every application.

Another solution is to get a replacement key in case you really can't insert the key back in your laptop, have you tried [a search for 'broken laptop key'](http://www.google.com/search?q=broken+laptop+key)?

Comment: This is th best solution I have found - unlike AutoHotKey and Keytweak, I can modify the characters generated with modifiers, without changing the unmodified behaviour. Now I can get ( and ) without Shift, 9 and 0 are unaffected! :D

Comment: Well, for my case of converting a `qwertz` keyboard into a `qwerty` keyboard this does not work, because ctrl+z stays next to the t. :(

Comment: For some applications that (presumably)  are listening to keydown events it is also necessary to also remap keyboard scan codes. It's a nice solution because it's built into windows and you can use the windows shortcuts.

Comment: The only problem is that it requires .NET Framework 2.0 - if you install it to run the keyboard layout creator, make sure you uninstall it after!

Comment: I wanted to interchange my backspace and caps lock. This method doesn't work for me.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"We're sorry, this download is no longer available."*. [Another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key/723334#723334) has a working link.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Microsoft's [Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134).
This will even allow you to add extra functionality to your keyboard, such as changing a key into a dead key (e.g. <kbd>~</kbd>), add extra mappings (e.g. <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> ->`ç`), etc.

In order to edit the special keystrokes, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>FOO</kbd>, you might need to edit the `.klc` file manually.
You can find instructions by [@Senseful](https://superuser.com/users/14797/senseful) in https://superuser.com/a/172993/157884 :

> You need to modify the `.klc` file manually.
>
> Basically you just modify the `VK_` column to match the value in
> column `1`.
>
> So for example if you want to bind <kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>N</kbd>, you
> would create the keyboard as you normally would in KLC. Then you would
> open the KLC file in a text editor. Find the value `L` in the `VK_`
> column, and switch it to an `N`.
>
> For more information, I wrote the [complete steps on my
> blog](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-keyboard-shortcuts-in-klc-eg.html).

### Warning: incomplete support for key bindings in some applications

However, be warned that some applications might not take those special keystrokes properly.

As an example: with my particular configuration, pressing <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in DotA2's teamchat will erase the text — instead of adding an `ã` like in other applications.

Answer (score 4):

I have Genius KB-G235 USB keyboard (HID) and WinXP SP3. Neither of applications in previous answers didnt work for me. (Because working with PS/2 codes or not (fully) with XP).

I tried HotkeyP (free and open source) https://sourceforge.net/projects/hotkeyp/ and this works! Just add action for key and its done. (After assign new action isn't default action executed.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way: **The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator**.
This is an official Microsoft solution. Functionality is similar like Ukelele for OS X.

Download and instructions: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134

Answer (score 2):

**[Keyman Desktop](http://keyman.com/)** - You can even create your own custom keyboards with [Keyman Developer](http://keyman.com/developer/). With keyboards for over 1000 languages, Keyman Desktop lets you type in your language even when Windows doesn’t.

Comment: The Keyman software is becoming free after SIL International bought it. This makes it a more interesting choice than before. (Few people would buy software to do just a simple mapping of a key for personal use.)

Answer (score 2):

#### For Windows 10: PowerToys

Microsoft has released an advanced application, [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/), that has a simple, but effective, key mapping facility.  I've used it to swap my <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys; it works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.autohotkey.com/ can be a simpler and powerful solution. You can remap keys and create modifiers keys using scripts like

```
;Use Capslock as a modifier and not as capslock anymore
$*Capslock::
    Gui, 99:+ToolWindow
    Gui, 99:Show, x-1 w1 +NoActivate, Capslock Is Down
    keywait, Capslock
    Gui, 99:Destroy
    return

;Write functions for keys while capslock is beeing hold here
#IfWinExist, Capslock Is Down
    j::Down
    k::Up
    l::Right
    h::Left
    m::AppsKey
    i::Insert
    d::Delete
#IfWinExist

;Use right and left shifts to toggle capslock
RShift & LShift::
    SetCapsLockState, % (State:=!State) ? "On" : "Off"
    return

LShift & RShift::
    SetCapsLockState, % (State:=!State) ? "On" : "Off"
    return
```

Comment: But why all of this if something like `ScrollLock::LControl` is just enough for the remapping?

Comment: Sorry, I really could simplify, but I wanted to show the power of the tool. With this script you don't need to sacrifice keys, you just need to have a modifier key and have a second function for one key.

Comment: Re *"I wanted to show the power of the tool"*: You could split the answer into two parts: The first part with a direct answer with the simplest solution that could possibly work and another more elaborate/comprehensive part. (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

I found one application, *[HotkeyP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hotkeyp/)*, which can do almost all of them in Windows 7 and it works without any issues when your desktop is unlocked. Also it is pretty easy to use.

The only drawback I found was it will not work when the desktop is locked, say, I come back from sleep and the computer is locked and I have loud music playing. Multimedia keyboards can mute from there itself. But with this application you need to unlock first.