# How to remap special keys on my keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

I have a mute button on my keyboard, which I use a lot. I also have three buttons I never use...Internet...Email...Search. Is there a hack that a novice user like me can do to get one of those three useless buttons to put my computer into "standby" mode?

Comment: I thought this was dupe as well, from the question title alone.  However, this asker wants to know specifically about using those other useless buttons on his uber-extended keyboard.

Comment: what brand and model of keyboard?

Comment: The keyboard that came with my eMachines computer...Keyboard Model# KB-9908

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found it!

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913065654/http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm)(archived), is all what you can find about key remapping. [Keytweak](https://web.archive.org/web/20130920155602/http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/)(archived) work fine for me, is a free keyboard remapper for Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/Win 7. It makes use of Microsoft's Scancode Map registry key to remap your keyboard.

[image]

This thing lets you remap one of your Internet / Email or Search keys to a sleep key !

It may not work for your keyboard model, make sure you have the latest driver.

Comment: @Revolter - You win the checkmark. A great piece of software, but I'm having one helluva time finding the right keyboard driver. Although my computer is an eMachines, the motherboard has been replaced. Googling the drive # gets lots of links. Haven't found one yet that works without trying to add something else to my computer. But it's a fun project so far. However, I've spent too many hours on it already. Don't know if it's worth the effort to continue, just to remap one stinking key. But I can see "Keytweak" coming in handy down the road. Thanks a million.

Comment: According to virustotal.com, Key Tweak does have a trojan :(. Here is the analyzed result of the installer http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=ddb0bad2a358191d2ee4ac8b8d359cc15e66a8dce6a49a8a6cd3b008f5345c1e-1286451622

Comment: Neither link works any more.

Comment: Confirming dead link

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to remap an existing key such as the shortcut ones - however you can do the following :

Open up notepad or any text editor and write :

> %windir%\system32\rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState

Save this anywhere (can be in any folder) as anything you like as long as it has an extension of .cmd or .bat

Next, make a shortcut to this script from anywhere and right click it. Set up a shortcut key - can be anything, but try not to use something that another application does - using a combination (2 or more) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> along with another key.

Now, whenenver you type this combination, you should go in to suspend.

[image]

Comment: I like it!  Neat

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to put a little time into it, you may be able to pull it off with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). See [How to catch special application keys?](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic2070.html)

Once you have the proper code for your key, I think you would put something like this in the AHK file:

```
[keycode]::Run %windir%\system32\rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```

To build on [Wil's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/72812/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-standby-in-windows-xp/72817#72817), that is.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, [Sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html) should be able to recognize the keys. This isn't really a separate application to interpret your keys, it's really a frontend for remapping the keys in the registry, which means you only need to do it once, and can then remove the program if you don't want to do it again. It could do with better roll-back features, however, so *back up your registry* before using it.

With this solution, you should not have to worry about your keyboard driver or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have another app installed to hook onto the keystroke, it looks as though default XP doesn't have one.

Linky: [MSFT XP Shortcuts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583)

With regard to hardware, what keboard are you using?

Comment: The one that came with my eMachines computer, Keyboard model # KB-9908