# My keyboard's "Esc" key not working, can i convert my "Insert" key into "Esc" throgh any software because i never use this key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

My keyboard's "Esc" key not working , I think it's hardware problem, can i convert my "Insert" or any other key  into "Esc", because i never use this key? or will I have to purchase a new keyboard for just one fault key?

"Insert" key that seems to serve no purpose whatsoever? In 7 years I don't remember ever pushing that button.

Comment: Do you know why it is not working? Software or Hardware?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key

Answer (score 0):

Not having tested it, [How to remap special keys on my keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/72812/how-to-remap-special-keys-on-my-keyboard) seems to provide an answer. So does [How can i remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key).

Answer (score 0):

re: purpose of insert key.

- Shift+Insert = paste
- Ctrl+Insert = Copy
- "Insert" on many text editors turns on [Overtype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtype) mode.