# Adjusting monitor brightness when the menu button is broken

Tags: display

I've got this LCD Monitor @ home that works but the "menu" button doesn't seem to be working. I need to be able to adjust the brightness, but how can I do that if I can't even get into the monitor's menu? Is there a software solution that I can use?

Comment: Did you try the other buttons on the monitor? Often the - or + buttons work as shortcuts to bring up the brightness and contrast settings without going through the menu.

Comment: Yes i've tried the other buttons. there's one that switches through preset "profiles" but that doesn't let me specify values. So far I'm using Powerstrip, but it's not completely free. it does the trick just fine, but as far as I can tell it's a trial piece of software.

Comment: I think PowerStrip is just nagware; haven't seen any proof of a 30 day limit or similar. Then again, I only tried it for a few minutes. Updated my answer with an application that does the job for me–quite psyched about it myself, since it also answered [a question I asked not so long ago](http://superuser.com/q/219859/56977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerstrip seems to work just fine for me. I haven't tried Display Tuner yet but i'm definitely going to take note of that in case I need it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the monitor entirely.

For starters, if it is in warranty, you may just want to get it replaced.

If it is a NEC monitor, there is a utility you can download to adjust brightness, look on the website for more details.

Again - even if it is not an NEC, you may want to take a look at the manufacturers website just in case there is a utility.

Next if it is a proper button that has fallen in/out, you may want to try using an object such as a pen/pencil to try to touch the contact that it would of.

If this doesn't work, you may be out of luck - short of opening the monitor and trying to fix the problem.

Comment: Well, video card control panels, color profiles and applications like f.lux come to mind, but I think the asker is hoping for a more practical solution than going through a whole series of actions. (So am I.)

Answer (score 2):

A great application that works very well for my monitor–the only one I've found so far that actually sets the monitor's brightness instead of the video card's–is [Display Tuner](http://www.nicomsoft.com/dtuner/).

Answer (score 0):

I also was suffering greatly from this problem - especially when external lighting was dim and the monitor would flashing powerful beams of light in my eyes. On computer with **integrated intel graphics**, you can use the Graphics Control Panel for brightness settings -

1. Right click on your desktop screen and select *Graphics Properties*. A [Intel HD Graphics Control Panel Startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jESrY.png) window (undecorated) should pop up.
2. The [Intel HD Graphics Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH3V2.png) will finally load. Click on the Display menu option.
3. On the upper part you will have a Color tab. Click on it.
4. In Color enhancement set the brightness to your setting, one by one, for each color red, green and blue.
5. There you go with the cool look.

Note that you should be having the proper driver for opening the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel.