# Can I change the display brightness via software on a Windows x64 desktop?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, display, brightness, display-settings

Now that monitors are all fancy and digital, display manufacturers lost sight of the utility of the brightness knob.  Of course I can go fiddle with the now-cumbersome digital brightness settings buried somewhere in the menus of each monitor, after I curse at my monitor because I hit the auto calibrate button by accident.  Then onto the right-hand-side monitor.  You get the idea.

Anyhow, is there any equivalent on a desktop PC to the proprietary key combinations laptop manufacturers use to quickly and easily adjust display brightness?

Answer (score 0):

I found this closely related [question and answer](https://superuser.com/q/219859/31240), though it doesn't work for me (I'm running Windows 7 64-bit)

> I think I just found the answer to my own question. Better solutions
>   are welcome of course.
>
> With the application [Display Tuner](http://www.nicomsoft.com/dtuner/) I can set the brightness,
>   contrast, color levels and speaker volume for my external monitor. Not
>   the video card, my actual monitor.   It allows me to set hotkeys for
>   separate profiles, lives in the tray (notification area) and is free
>   for non-commercial use.   The main draw is that it only supports
>   monitors that can be controlled through [DDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel).

[image: Display Tuner screenshot]