# Change screen brightness over regular intervals

Tags: windows-7, windows, brightness

I am looking for a program that can change my computer (and [ASUS laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K53SC/)) screen brightness every hour. I want my screen brightness very low at night and bright during the day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/). This handle little program adjusts your screens color ratio to something easier on the eyes based on the time of day.

Comment: Jikag, I knew there is f.lux for IOS but I wouldn't think it was available for windows already. I guess I had to be more careful before I start writing a question. Thank you.

Comment: Note that f.lux does not change the brightness but the temperature.

Comment: @a_maar, I just noticed what you said. when I plugged in the charger, the brightness goes all the way up. Do you know any alternative solution to this? F.lux saves my eyes for now, I need also a brightness changer... God, I wish flux would do the both...

Comment: Love F.lux, and how the tone of my screen changes throughout the day, and also reminds me to go home!

Comment: @MehmetBudak Take a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/219859/is-there-a-quick-automatic-way-to-change-monitor-brightness-at-night-on-windows