# How to invert all colors on the monitor?

Tags: windows, display

How to change white color to black color and black color to white color displaying from the monitor?

Any developed software? Should I write a program with APIs? (and... with which APIs?)

Thanks

Comment: Also related: [Is there a quick/automatic way to change monitor brightness at night on Windows 7 or Linux?](http://superuser.com/q/219859/228536)

Comment: There may be an option in your video-adapter’s drivers/software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you actually want to invert all colors, not just black and white. In Windows 7, (and probably Vista and Windows 8 too) start magnifier (*Start* menu → *Accessories* → *Ease of Access*, or <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), click the gear icon to show settings, and check "turn on color inversion".

This only works if you're using Aero, not with the classic theme, or if your graphics driver doesn't support Aero.

[image]