# How to automatically set external monitor britghtenss to minimum whenever it is switched on?

Tags: automation, external-display, brightness

I have an Acer laptop running windows 10, and I occasionally connect a Lenovo external monitor through HDMI to see things in a bigger screen. Unfortunately, the external display defaults to brightness 70 when I connect it. I then have to manually press the buttons to reduce brightness. How can I make it so that it defaults to a brightness of 0?

Comment: is this what you're asking for: https://superuser.com/questions/219859/is-there-a-quick-automatic-way-to-change-monitor-brightness-at-night-on-windows

Comment: @Sanu_012, no, I was looking for something else. Using softwares would not be automatic. I would have to set it each time I open the external monitor.