# How to remap HID keyboard keys?

Tags: keyboard, sleep, key-binding, hid

I got some "close to useless" USB sleep buttons for computers from a marketing campaign and was wondering how to use it to something cooler. Like.. Playing [sad trombone](http://www.sadtrombone.com/) when pressed.

So I went around looking how does it installs, and finally seems to be simply a HID keyboard key. Googlin' a bit more, I've found [Patriot's question](https://superuser.com/q/72812/45990) which seemed quite the answer - but no. The programs they describe there do not trap the commands from the USB dongle even in "teach mode" if I press it my computer goes to sleep -_-

What would be the correct way to find and remap that key to something specific?

**Edit** Forgot to mention the operation system. it is Windows 7

Comment: what os?  evtest in linux is pretty good for trapping keyboard scankeys - there's vaguely similar things in windows but nothing as good

Comment: Oh, darnit.. Totaly forgot to mention. It is windows 7 I am using.

Comment: Apparently some of those keys have the key-combination they send out hardcoded in an [eeprom](http://hackaday.com/2012/02/28/reprogramming-promotional-usb-dongles-to-launch-custom-urls/) cracking one open might be educational

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this [Keyboard Layout tool by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) lets you remap a key on an existing layout.
Apparently it is a GUI that lets you edit the registry settings for your keyboard mapping.
You can also trying hacking the registry keys under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout

Good luck. (fade out:  whaaa-whaaaarmmm)