# How to Remap "Home" button on a Local Multimedia Keyboard without Driver

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently purchased a multimedia keyboard (TECHNOTECH USB KEYBOARD 658) that is actually Made in China, and that doesn't come with ny driver CD or anything.

[image]
Here I want to map **Home** button to **Calculator** button, as **Home** button is of no use to me, and I want to use it as **Calculator**. This **Home** button opens the Google Chrome window (my default browser).

But unfortunately as it is a product from some Local Vendor, and they have not provided any CD like Microsoft does.

I tried various software like **SharpKeys** but that says that that **Home** key on my keyboard is not recognized.

[image]

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate. Basically I believe what you are looking for is to remap extra keys that aren't normally there for normal keyboards.  If this what you are looking for check out this solution.

[How to remap special keys on my keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/72812/how-to-remap-special-keys-on-my-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a Microsoft keyboard with a bunch of keys like this (Home, Search, Email, Favourites, ...) which I never use.

[Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4052277/accessories-how-do-i-reassign-hot-keys-for-my-keyboard) provides a UI for remapping these keys to all kinds of other functions. You can set up macros for more advanced use cases, though I haven't needed to. In my case I wanted to be able to skip to the next song in my media player from the keyboard, and that was available out of the box.

[image]