# How to set Link for Windows Browser Home Button? [SOLVED]

Tags: windows, keyboard, internet

On my Keyboard I have a key with a Home Icon, when I press that the Standardbrowser opens with a Webpage that I dont like, so how can I change that page to be google?

Comment: I guess you simple need to change your start page in the standard browser.

Comment: Already tryed that (Chrome), if im in Chrome and press the Home button im on a New Tab site(thats ok) but if im not in chrome and press that key it  sends me to the site i dont like

Comment: Take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/72812/how-to-remap-special-keys-on-my-keyboard

Comment: Im trying to solve the Issue using Windows only because some Form of Adware changed the Page it theoretically should work in Registry or somewhere else

Comment: Usually such keyboards come with a Utility program to configure them ...

Comment: @DavidPostill There is no Utility program for this keyboard, also tryed another old Keyboard and that problem is there as well so Its not the Fault of the Keyboard

Comment: Try setting the homepage of internet explorer.