# Remapping keyboard keys for specific applications

Tags: keyboard, macros, remapping

I want to be able to remap keys for specific applications so that those keys can execute macros. I don't want the remap to be global. What are the best programs for this?

Comment: What applications?  What OS?

Comment: Judging by his other questions ill have to guess Windows

Comment: For permanently remapping keys, see [this question: How can I remap a keyboard key?](http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key?lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to make context-sensitive hotkeys that will work **only if a certain window is active** (so it will not work globally):

```
#IfWinActive Reminders ahk_class #32770  ; The "reminders" window in Outlook.
Enter::Send !o  ; Have an "Enter" keystroke open the selected reminder
#IfWinActive
```

[More on  #IfWinActive here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)