# Using AutoHotKey to remap keys

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, gaming

I recently purchased Rayman 2 from GOG.com. The game is old and thus does not give the option to remap keys, and I'd like to make them a little closer to what we're used to today.

[image: Here's a screenshot from the manual with the key bindings.]

Basically, I want normal movement with WSAD, jump with space, and shoot with left mouse click. Also, I'd like the keys to only be remapped when the Rayman window is active. I created the below script, but it does not work correctly.

This is the first time I've ever worked with AHK, so I'm not sure what to do. How can I correctly configure the script?

Here's what happens with this script active:

- Script is active whether Rayman is open or not, let alone whether the window is active. (The window name can either be `Rayman II` or `Rayman2`.)
- W: moves forward and turns camera to the right
- S: works as intended
- A: moves left and jumps
- D: works as intended
- LButton: works as intended
- space: shoots and jumps

The script itself:

```
IfWinActive, Rayman2
{
    w::up
    s::down
    a::left
    d::right
    space::a
    LButton::space
}
```

Comment: @50-3 nope, AutoHotkey has always been used extensively to remap and disable keys. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm‎

Comment: @user 99572 I retract my previous statement and have some reading to do (:

Comment: Related, general question: [Remapping keyboard keys for specific applications](http://superuser.com/questions/88238/remapping-keyboard-keys-for-specific-applications)

Answer (score 4):

1. First, you're using the wrong command. Use `#IfWinActive`. This is for the whole script. The command you chose checks if a window is active within a script.
2. Then, check with WindowSpy what the ahk_class of the window is (which is useful if the window title changes). WindowSpy is included in the AutoHotkey installation.
3. Last, try different [SendModes](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm). There are a few that vary in the details. More info on the different Send commands can be found [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).

Your code will look something like this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class xyz ; put your ahk_class instead of xyz
SendMode Play ; try all of the following: Input|Play|Event|InputThenPlay

    w::up
    s::down
    a::left
    d::right
    space::a
    LButton::space
```

**Qualification:** Depending on the Windows version you're using, simulating key presses may or may not work. What works up to Windows 7, may not work in Windows 8 anymore. It has happened to me too and I haven't figured out an alternative within AutoHotkey yet.

You may need to try a different macro software (AutoIt, PhraseExpress, Macro Express).

Comment: `#IfWinActive` is exactly what I needed, thank you! However, the second part is not working. Having `SendMode Play` caused AHK to have no effect in the game, but using any of the other options caused the exact same results as in my original post.

Comment: @StevenH, I've adapted my answer a litte. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have keys mapped to each other which can cause circular calling.  Try putting a `$` in front of each of your keys.  That will prevent that problem.

Example:

```
$w::up
```

[Source](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Regarding your `IfWinActive` issue, I would suggest using `ahk_exe` instead.  Just look up the process name in Task Manager and put the following line before all of your hotkeys.

```
#If WinActive("ahk_exe rayman.exe")  ; Rename exe to whatever it really is
```

[Source](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_If.htm)

Comment: Good thought, but the $ unfortunately did not work.