# Change/swap keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

How can I switch my pgup/dn keys on my netbook with home/end? Here's my keyboard layout:

[image]

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Snark FTFY ...

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the **[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)** and change the keyboard layout to your likings.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

```
PgUp::Home
PgDn::End
Home::PgUp
End::PgDn
```

Comment: This would have been my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or [Key Tweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/):

> KeyTweak is a simple utility that allows users to redefine their
>   keyboard input  signals.  The functionality is made possible by a
>   registry value first documented in   Windows 2000, but also present in
>   Windows NT 4.0.  and included in XP, Vista and  Windows 7.  This
>   section lists some of KeyTweak’s features and reasons you may want  to
>   use KeyTweak.

[image]