# How can I restore Ctrl+<key> functionality in Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

I'm using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx), and I was able to successfully define my own keyboard. The problem is that now when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<key> combinations, it doesn't use my new key but instead uses the old key that exists there.

For example, if I bind <kbd>N</kbd> to <kbd>B</kbd>, you would expect that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> would now send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> but instead it sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

How can I get these Ctrl+Key combinations to use my new keys instead?

I tried adding the keys to the "Ctrl" layout, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to modify the `.klc` file manually.

Basically you just modify the `VK_` column to match the value in column `1`.

So for example if you want to bind <kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>N</kbd>, you would create the keyboard as you normally would in KLC. Then you would open the KLC file in a text editor. Find the value `L` in the `VK_` column, and switch it to an `N`.

For more information, I wrote the [complete steps on my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122064240/http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-keyboard-shortcuts-in-klc-eg.html).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to remap the Japanese keyboard keys in Windows?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1365453/remap-japanese-keys-in-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator

Comment: your solution works like a charm. but why is KLC and the windows ecosystem so barely usable?

Comment: If this didn't help, restart your computer. On Windows 10 Pro 64 VK_ values were cashed somewhere, so when I was switching to my own keyboard layout after I rebuilt keyboard layout with this manual fix on VK_, I still couldn't get desired changes. After restart, everything worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: the blog link is dead. So column 1 has the capital letters, and those work. the lower case letters do not in the VK_ column!