# Remap Japanese Keys in Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?

Tags: keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

The Japanese keyboard has 5 additional keys. I'm using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4, and I was able to successfully define my own keyboard layout. The problem is that now the 5 Japanese keys are essentially useless.  Is there a way to define these keys using the built-in features of Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?

Comment: Maybe you can do that by directly editing the *.klc file similarly to what is described for example [here](https://superuser.com/a/172993/) and [here](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-keyboard-shortcuts-in-klc-eg.html). [This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms927178(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) lists things that sound relevant: `VK_DBE_KATAKANA`, `VK_DBE_HIRAGANA`

Comment: @root to my knowledge caps lock modifiers like shift and control and hiragana can’t be modified but I’ll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not with the GUI but you can assign the keys to duplicate another key on your keyboard using sharp keys.