# Custom keyboard layout does not display double struck characters

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have created a custom layout with [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134)

When I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>keyCombo</kbd>, it is supposed to map to a [BQN symbol.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/primitive.html) These symbols are generally related to math notation, and have high unicode values.

My problem after installing my created layout is that the keyboard combos for  are not working, where:

```
(double struck lowercase w) - Right Alt+w
(double struck uppercase w) - Right Alt+Shift+w
(double struck lowercase x) - Right Alt+x
(double struck uppercase x) - Right Alt+Shift+x
(double struck lowercase s) - Right Alt+s
(double struck uppercase s) - Right Alt+Shift+s
(double struck lowercase g) - Right Alt+g
(double struck uppercase g) - Right Alt+Shift+g
(double struck lowercase r) - Right Alt+r
```

and so on. Basically, Right Alt + character should produce the respective double struck character.

The symbols display fine within the MSKLC editor(test keyboard layout option), but do not display when installed from a generated binary.

I am testing this layout on Windows 10, 64-bit, Build 19043.1110.

This is my .klc file which I made in MSKLC: [Pastebin](https://dzaima.github.io/paste#0lVlbd9pIEn7u/hV9eJlk1t7oBhK7c/askFqgWEiKLsb2yxwBImZMwAEymcyv36puYQShs46To2q1Wv1V173EzcAngw8x6UTVt82XPVtstmz6ec0@rr49P@6umLvaD7dvtsuPj3tWrfZvr6vZfvlnta/nHUq9JL3PwuGoIJ1hGomJcerG96STVX/X@@WnGuaixHMjHrtjTjr1@rrMX@ZCn3Q0/LO0Pkze8iwPk5jo/9QozUdhUOSFW3BKNfLunbdZffm0ZhbVjzdd9i@WPy721DjO9WBO/nn77Yr2jk/skyd4MGofnzrNXq2nNHLvk7Ig5N/VmtV/7bcV@@W/v7Bqz/aPNavXc7bcsYrN62rOnupvlL57l3vk9uZ3QrzqmWhEJwbpERvmr6/JNfwReVVd4KQGvCTe1DRDJ9dAjblDDNPpE@CV@eEwLFgS8yvG77zIHbsFSIyN3ezmiv223qzr/1yxQcZvYYEXZl7EfTZKsvAhiQs3YgM3Y5OwGLE4KbwRe/NcfdnVb6lmAqOAahBUhUDVKkDtOXYLtZgksGkyHvPMC2EztzhC@qHLM56H@RWbjMKCN@ASDF5kflLkVLOIiTgmns5EHEOzZ3C67qKNM8o4sB@X4wHPWB4O4yNOXqZgJF4WpgXjH0o3ypsFbhqxoIw9FAfwlt@PB0l04ALMKKNal1gIbiG4JcBNHcC7i14LPEjKDI6TRJF7jl0kKYt4UIAMsphnl04aJRNgWXgEA@78zI0LqvVIF4G7CNyV0p1axDD6Ths4RJ3B6TweF2fIrlcCkOvho6Ne/fA2RH9heeTmI6rZYGsA04Ptu3VjOnM0naoFk4d3codyHET87mXTF0Um5SDiCsQiC914CI/9ZBKzN9NtXT2B9TjERmAbz9dDYBtQrbqNCgaJShqj9tzYbxtO@/lFJQqwwvVu2PukYL9SrU8cxHMQrxKKNPQarajbguSoBNgyL3gW5i3vCOMgjMPiXgVXpidgFekjWB/BnMY1FsSw67by4hA9UhhH6mYgs5H0hQPm2PWyJEYKT9BnIfrJ5VKegwwQOZjKFKDgv4ZofekghoFobfd/4Bl4orSyi3CDMop4cQYn15/hzUjCx7@Pw7jMJegcrWchz7mwUbLSekb36YjH12LlFdo5i8SZj3o8GKOw3BysP@MsSxIAmQuQNGowTMQwphJjjhgz6YEnDo3Lz9xgXEZFmEZwmqKFBL7NErArt0gyqmvkA4Ho@RmI8HAAM/S@lF4E78FrYzdC4RdgGOzDVTPruWlYuO35F@f7cWQJI5BCDmlixCY8BwFnWTKhuk4myMdXIMCHPu/2HLw2XnGBk4mCk0nbilrqlI56nRdZCcYqt5r8cM1hY@DOIBy5q4EI9wErN0zbVvHGFby19C/X84iPMXwlgUpuPM3DCJRXxj7PIB1R3SQZ8rIFgrzofSkuU8VMpmAmOzJTphM383Opi1fIDbiwSIFc7IEIiRgihk1VTBQKJlqRNEqGAlCEO0Vk41HhShuiepfcE8gR34AAB0gU2PcK7PsW9k@8RfUeKfHsX4CIs/ctnLgMXiq2KVumIH3fK1PVWqrbJETIJRAB6SwQV1ehhoqdwu9Qw7E75ML@ziZYkskAA3mc6g5JEH8DRB5Zw4uhwk8U@Ml3@FBrDUNUcYuF1twpF32SIhfPQDAYmjMN3VBp@Sp5pkcuhlA63Zy9FarML0wKl0J8x@gsSiMI/ZCANHvaeCIKpWrYwWTVnKfJHk3C88osuj/OvZggPDvxQrEYMyvVpwKy10BiOrDnDaSBkFIPMmGdY8pZBah4eIIql0vYmrgo7gqIyA1WHxF7KnG7CnG7r8wNAwAVpRnUskl2lh8WJEdedkCa/GCJ/FCpuMkV3OQ/kR/yV@WHnBoa8ZG7ORCpli5OXGbMVzDmt@OxLOIOlnBxOYV@J0DUBRApk66NV0jhCuhAsVfwEzIJXiWTgEIZNkTuPgJpuBMZ3VRm9KGCu@FPcDd8FXdDCt3UCLl7BCIC2hSr40qZv0YK3kZn1dbYTaXnXqdJGMMLw5cOQRSSH0qIIS8tKNTL0Fm9R0b@ACIrcwcnLnPxXsHF@7ZHA@ShvFMtp9BW3SDqExBE7c6mWPspVXOj2KnVJrSbu//j6NApUGh8IuRgBQQ5sOczbPOUCogUHESnEbSlBRHJXq0GW4RYXYZYE6O62bRKM2yAp7LWy/k49JIIW5OGtBr6cRL7LdGPQ98XrR8c1hG723J3QzR@howUVR/bTllvu2kChppA43B1xqEyTcg2epQkN9iKQrQcJLecvRlX63m1Xa6Z97hc17uarcT3qD3s8ZZCo4TcmJKbHl7sQ/@LSqhmgpth5t4eW1qoufzvytdmMk5kA04Nmai6TaLCzeyZ7FsONyJRcfxyBc1AEoU@tkdw27R4Jz3Sj9dRY0Ye0IT@BoKy7EMyeFDZz4PCfh7O7AdK7AHGX5kHxZ0IxSM3SxNU@OVdKDSCd8jMX0CaBNUXCWqh4uhOsdfdT4S7u1eFuztq1MRD7mZAZIIyceIyY56CMa/91WMSnxYrF1@gxoLcIu6fQGSbgN/musq68Vax0@33bQK6mLJLaHoEUyMDhJ8CERWM6Ns0RwU/UMAPzowkiBIRXEU5x0OwxiE1dRIj1hqI@A5hLnDiMpDKjloBRTR8RQjOzNeb/fJps36reomaBhkj9icgQsw9cVGKeazYadz66uOD2wtBF4n08PYMNU3h6fh105VBDf3bnEl4SCQAbwl4sQRllefXxciNz75RhDE6NfeBoYd7UbS9LGyX/qYlv4nwLEx8CVgjYC0BrTkCys9ZQYmVW5Gkorp34VyXcGHn8BY/sxfigCcrT4C7AthoQvcCQReNkKHc1@eaTAyHEPWhhKL1@7CNAjzs2Q7ih6wkilyzT/LU9XiD1Vyu9ea/wMHnVwdy2P2U0q5JfO5BFoyOkjLq041aUmoN8R@l9Ibf488PlGo64bsZ1WoyqGZPu@dqVlNtQYpqSvUZ4et9vaX6nIhfDoyK5I/LxZ6aPdLJRL4R9x1q2qQTf/nEfoWhQ/CXAjyp2AySbMernncs2sye4PGUBDoFMwoMCmVsYFLQcGBREHnQpZZGgh61oOy1qWWQwKGWSYI@tSx4S6NWl6T4fZ5awEA@225Wq2Zbq2HAhqEjhw4M@3LYh2Elh9cwnMqhBcOZHHZhOJfDHgxrOfwHDBdyqHdoV5NDA4a6HJowNORQ66BSxNCvV3BjAYffdiyrP8ONDezrFMrjQDco5MhANyk0eIFuUUjMgd6lNpxf71EHBKDb1AEJ6A51QAR6nzogA0OjDgjB0KnTBWJQpwfEpA5sbVgvCv2d3xUUNSc4EerroP4adaEaO2jx4vE7qbh0uwZFzrZrobxmJeiwg/IWCxsZ98gAv2@jsEebTzVKunwWQk6rjzUrn4VsoxosBKQp9kEB8vUchedvvq6F5MRivBPSC9e7ersXFl2v6n2NkvtN08DGe2RUr54pNOAd3JNNluv55usO3poduDxOzYn7/Lxazqr9crOm1OfyJxHw0xyM3NL65Kd/zcNfu@Jh6Q7FL3WHbfj642q5e2RvyvUSFrF8D2t3bynlsX8z8On/AA). The main goal of this keyboard layout is to create a reliable way to type BQN glyphs on windows without any extra applications, so I would appreciate if the solution was based around editing the klc file.

Comment: Instead of sending us to look into the `.klc` file (that doesn't work), could you clearly state what you expect each key-combination to produce, meaning which characters should be send to the program.

Comment: @harrymc I've added a bit more on that. Basically, Right Alt + Letter should give the double struck version of the letter(if the letter is in `wWsSxXfFgGr`). The rest fo the symbols work fine.

Comment: For someone like me, please spell out which characters exactly are to be sent.

Comment: ok, I'll add all of them to the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the standard Windows keyboard layout, together with
the third-party product [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

You could use a AutoHotkey script such as the following to map
<kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to "ww" and
<kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to "WW":

```
RAlt & w::
    ShiftState := GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
    If (ShiftState) {
        Send, 
    } Else {
        Send, 
    }
return
```

The other keys are easy to do by a slight modification of the above
two lines.

Notes:

- The `.ahk` file must be saved in mode UTF-8-BOM
  (easy to do using Notepad++)
- The Double-Struck characters I just copied from the `compart.com`
  pages:

  and
  ,
  which is why the script file must be in format of UTF-8 with BOM.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: "Double struck w" means `Mathematical Double-Struck Small W`: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D568

Comment: OK, now I know... I corrected the script ,which came out longer than before because of AutoHotkey idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Hm, I may as well just implement the whole layout in autohotkey.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting, because this will work. MSKLC is very limited in what it can do, and it can't do complicated key combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen when trying to use the new shortcuts in all programs or just certain ones?  Most of those keys already have shortcuts defined in Office programs. It's possible you have to do some additional modification of the .klc file, as noted in the answers here
[How can I restore Ctrl+<key> functionality in Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?](https://superuser.com/questions/171307/how-can-i-restore-ctrlkey-functionality-in-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator?rq=1)

Comment: It is consistently not wokring across chrome, firefox, notepad and emacs.