# Modify Windows Default Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

Is there a tool to modify Windows default keyboard shortcuts?

For instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> opens the Start menu. I'd like to change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoHotkey or Autoit or one of the other hotkey programs will allow you to do that.

I'm not sure that you modify windows to allow you to do this. I know you can specify shortcuts for programs shortcuts on your desktop, but I believe that is the extent of it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this in Windows natively.  You gotta break out the third party programs.