# How to remap keys on a laptop keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

I'm using an HP EliteBook 8440p laptop and two of the keys on my keyboard (<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd>) aren't working. Replacing the keyboard will take 2-3 days, and I can't stop my office work.

I'm bored of using the on-screen keyboard for writing "v" and "b", and I don't have any portable USB keyboards to connect to the laptop right now.

I'm thinking that, since I'm not using the <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and <kbd>Pg Down</kbd> keys at all, is there any software or trick which can remap those keys to "v" and "b", respectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) will allow you to do this.

Comment: Bingo.. thank you very much.. (Now I typed v and b using pg up and pg down in this comments..) :P