# Exchanging 2 keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

Is it possible to replace/exchange the function of 2 keys? Actually I bought a new laptop and it's shift key is behind "\" key and I always hit "\" key while pressing "Shift Key". So I was wondering if I could exchange their functionality?

Adil

Answer (score 2):

You can use keyboard remapping tools like [these](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remap-keyboard-free-tools-windows/)

[image]

- Officially supports all editions of Windows 8, Windows 7 and Windows Vista
- Changes are made at a low level so that they take effect in all programs and 3D games
- This remapper does not need to be loaded in memory all the time
- Supports disabling of keys rather than remapping them