# How to modify key bindings in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, key-binding

I have a new laptop which combines the PgUp/Home and PgDn/End keys, requiring a function key to be pressed for the Home/End use.  Since I regularly use Home and End, but rarely use Page Up/Down I want to rebind the keys in Windows 8 (I have already done so in linux).  I haven't been able to find information regarding where/how to modify key bindings in this way.  How can it be done?

Comment: Also see [How can I remap a keyboard key?](http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found a [lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows) which covers this.  It suggests using an application called KeyTweak, available for free.  The lifehacker page was having some loading issues making the links harder to click, so [here is the download page for KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/).  I used this to adjust my keys in Windows 8, with no problems.

I found the half teach mode to be particularly helpful.  In this mode, you press a button which causes the application to "listen" for a key press.  When one occurs, it identifies the exact button identifier (in my case these were 5 digit numbers).  You can then select from a list the button action you want associated with that key press.  There is also a full teach mode, however I did not try that.  All changes are prepared and not put into effect until you click apply (and restart).

Comment: Dead link: download page for KeyTweak

Comment: I've got it from here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml

Comment: I got it from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130926034451/http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/KeyTweak%20Manual.pdf<br>
https://web.archive.org/web/20130926034451/http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/KeyTweak_install.exe<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;the most recent snapshot before the website was taken down<br>

Answer (score 0):

[Autohotkey!](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

With keyboard remapping you are able to change, disable, modify keyboard functions to make them act like other keys or assign hot-keys to replace keyboard combinations.

Some folks have noticed that AHK doesn't behave well in windows 8, but I followed the advice [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126160517/http://geekswithblogs.net/deadlydog/archive/2012/09/10/autohotkey-cannot-interact-with-windows-8-windowshellipor-can-it.aspx) and have happily remapped.