# Change the Windows key to Caps Lock in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, capslock

I often use the Windows key in order to switch between workspaces. However, the Windows key is located in a rather uncomfortable position finger-wise, so I would like to change it to the Caps Lock key (which I never use anyway). How can I do this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a response to another user on an application to remap keys on a windows computer.  You could also use AHK to do this as well.

[Here is a good article from Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) by using a utility called [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

https://superuser.com/a/36922/273858