# Shortcut key for delete

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

My delete key is not working and I feel happy if I can create shortcut for both temporarily and permanently delete files using other keys.Can any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always use the "On screen keyboard" built into windows, assuming that is what you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remap a keyboard key?](http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key)

Answer (score 3):

for temporarily delete use right-click key (on keyboard [image]) and press <kbd>D</kbd> and for permanently deleting press right-click key then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Done! you don't need scripting :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with a script containing:

```
Del::^X
```

where `^X` is read Ctrl+x. See the format [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).