# Win 10 upgrade ctrl + backspace login

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, login, backspace

I have used this exact combination as my password on my both my computers running windows 7. I uppgraded one of them to windows 10 and it seems that the program wich u write the password in to on win10 uses this ctrl + backspace as deleting the whole word. This meens i cant get the correct symbol to my password to login.
 How should i proceed?

Comment: In NotePad `Ctrl-Bksp` generates `0x7F`, but I don't know of an alternative key combination, or whether the W10 password input routine will handle this any differently. Even pasting from the clip-board doesn't work. I think the only way you are going to get past this is by changing the password. If you haven't enabled an alternative account with a password you can type, you should be able to do it in safe mode, or failing that with an installation or diagnostic disc. You could also try changing the log-in to use an MS account, where you can set a usable password.

Answer (score 0):

My way would be to:

1. check what symbol shows up when you type Ctrl+Bckspc
2. get a [code of this symbol](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html) for example from [here](http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/)
3. then use tools described [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key), probably AutoHotkey, to assign behaviour of Ctrl+Bckspc to a specific symbol (that you get in the previous steps)

As far as I see AutoHotkey enables you to highly customise hotkey scripts, so I would expect it to work.

However, this will likely disable this handy option to erase whole word using Ctrl+Bckspc.