# Is it possible to change the keys windows uses for mousekeys?

Tags: windows, mouse

Windows has a feature called [mouse keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer). Is there any way to make it use other keys?

For example rather than use the numberpad I'd rather use QWE/ASD/ZXC instead of the 789/456/123 that it comes with.

I'm interested particularly in modern versions of windows (7/8/10)

This is slightly different from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key) as that solution isn't easy to toggle; with the built in mouse keys you can toggle the keys on/off with NumLock but for that answer you have to logout/reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to in your last paragraph (the proposed duplicate has 8 solutions)?  You're saying not a single one solves your problem?  Unless you can better clarify how your question is different, it will attract the same answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you that isn't even third party :)

Install Microsoft Keyboard layout creator from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Watch this video on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87bt7GBM02M

As you will see towards the end of the video there is an overlay menu that allows her to toggle between her modified keyboard and her regular keyboard without having to reboot every time.  She did indicate that a single reboot may be necessary but that is only required one time.

I also thought it would be worth mentioning that if you're looking for something even smoother than that, buy yourself a nice macro keyboard.  I have the deathstalker from razar and it is able to have different profiles with different key bindings attached to it.  I hope this helps!