# Change Windows keyboard shortcuts for applications

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

Are there any way to set a custom keyboard shortcut for an application in Windows?
More specifically I'd like to overwrite the exisisting <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut (which is default for opening `Windows Explorer`)

I think it might be possible to do it with *AutoHotKey* , but I'm looking for a more native solution, e.g. a registry hack, so I don't have to depend on third-party software.

I saw *SharpKeys* were noted in another post ( [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key) ), but I'm not sure if that can set application specific shortcuts, only change the function of keys. Regardless, this is also third-party software.

Lastly, I'm aware of custom keyboard shortcut for **shortcuts**, but these are limited to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd><wanted key></kbd>.

I've been unsuccessful Googling for this but perhaps my Google Fu level is not high enough. Ultimately I may have to settle for AutoHotKey, but any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to overwrite it such that you can use`WIN`+ `E` for something else, or do you just want another shortcut to open Windows explorer?

Comment: I would like to overwrite WIN+E to start another application than Windows Explorer. Just thought I'd make the question more generic because I'd also love to create other custom shortcuts like WIN+W etc. This is solved very elegantly in Linux where I can manually enter command for any key bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't know how you could do this, but I will think about it.