# How to expand folders without numlock key on my keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, numlock

I'm working with a new computer (Windows 10), but the keyboard does not contain a <kbd>Numlock</kbd> key.
On a normal computer, on which Windows is installed, the shortcut <kbd>Numlock + *</kbd> expands all subfolders in a Windows Explorer.

On the internet, I've already found some posts mentioning the usage of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, but also this key is not present on my keyboard.

Does anybody know how I can expand all folders on my computer, or does anybody know how I can reveal all Windows shortcut keys, working on my computer? (When I can see this, I assume I will be able to add/modify them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key at all.

Just press <kbd>*</kbd> on your numpad.

If you don't have a numpad on your keyboard, you can reassign an unused key to function as the <kbd>Num*</kbd> (numpad asterisk) using an external program such as [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) as listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key), which works globally across Windows (there's a way to do this through registry editing, which is basically what that program does for you), or you can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to remap the key only when you're using Windows Explorer.

Here's an example for an AutoHotkey script that makes the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key behave like <kbd>Num*</kbd> when the window focus is on a Windows Explorer window:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass
    Insert::NumpadMult
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
    Insert::NumpadMult
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this without using NumLock like I said?

Comment: First I proposed you try simply pressing the asterisk on your numpad without using NumLock. You don't have one, then?

Answer (score 0):

Tomer's answer works great, but if for whatever reason you want to recreate the actual shortcut this Autohotkey script remaps the shortcut to the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key:

```
PrintScreen:: 
SetNumLockState, On
Send {NumpadMult}
SetNumLockState, Off
return
```