# keyboard key "u" stopped working

Tags: windows, keyboard

My "u" key stopped working on my laptop keyboard. I'm sure this is a technical problem, probably the contact oxidised or something. Do you know any way to create a combination of keys that types "u"? For example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. Or maybe if I can entirely change a key, for example when pressing any number pad key (like 4 or 0) to type "u" instead. I'm only doing this until I repair my main problem.

EDIT: Windows 10, Dell Laptop (if it helps).

Comment: Select "u", hit Ctrl + C, then Ctrl + V is the answer. Other ways may be OS-dependent. What is your OS?

Comment: I merged my accounts.I have windows 10.So any idea for my problem?

Comment: AutoHotkey *maybe*. This is not an answer because I have never used this software. If this is the right tool then anybody feel free to write a high quality answer and take credit; I won't.

Answer (score 2):

You can reassign an unused key to function as <kbd>u</kbd> using an external program such as [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) as listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key), which works globally across Windows (there's a way to do this through registry editing, which is basically what that program does for you), or you can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) if you want a key combination to do this.

The advantage of the former is you don't need to run anything; the operating system does it for you. It basically turns your assigned key to <kbd>u</kbd>. I did this once when one of my keys stopped working (I sacrificed my seldom-used <kbd>Menu</kbd> key between the right-hand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

The advantage of the latter is, as mentioned, that it allows key combinations.

Here's an example for an AutoHotkey script that makes the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> key combination behave like the <kbd>u</kbd> key:

```
!1::u
```

And one for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>:

```
^4::u
```

You can find more information on the various keys and modifiers in the AutoHotkey documentation (I'd put links, but my reputation isn't high enough for that apparently).

Answer (score 0):

You could try typing it by using the unicode entry (ALT + 117) on the number keypad.
You might find this page interesting: [Numpad Key Combos](http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one key that does not work, you could try cleaning the contacts (they may be dirty or greasy). I just did on mine and it worked great, but it may not work for you or not be possible on some keyboard models.

1. Remove the key cap to expose the scissor mechanism below.
2. Use a small screwdriver to carefully dislodge the the scissor and remove it.
3. Cut a small strip of paper (0.4cm x 4cm) and slide it behind the switch. Your goal is to get it between the two membranes with one wire each. Use the long side to guide it.
4. Gently press the switch while the paper is in there, and begin pulling on the paper to remove the dirt and grease.
5. Remove the paper completely and test the key on a text editor.
6. If it did not work, you can try again.
7. Reassemble the scissor mechanism and put the key cap back on.