# How do assign keyboard multimedia keys to our purpose for char insertion

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, windows-8.1, keyboard, unicode

My keyboard has 10 multimedia keys

this site and net search tell that those key can be assigned to software to do specific function like "run browser", "reduce/ increase volume", "start calc"

But due to my need to typing in unicode, I regularly have to use some more keys that are not present in keyboard.

Can I assign these 10 keyboard multimedia keys to give unicode char say in word/ excel. How?

say, I want "reduce volume" key to insert "A" in ms word (of course, it will give A every where in windows whenever pressed). how to do that? I use w10-64, w8.1-64

Thanks.

Comment: 1st. you check whether your keyboard latest driver + software + guide mentioned that you can assign this key : [ Alt + 0222(numpad) ]. If successful can you should get this Þ character. || you can use "character map" in windows to check the equivalent key for the characters you need.

Comment: 8.1 device driver screen tells 
Standard PS/2 Keyboard
Driver provider - Microsoft
Driver Date - 6/21/2006
Driver Version - 6.3.9600.17808.
I couldn't understand where to find the "software, guide" that you mentioned.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the brand of your multimedia keyboard? You can normally find the extra software, guide/manual from the manufacturer support webpage. ( I knew Logitech does.)

Comment: DataLink's ProDot PS/2 Keyboard model KB-107m PS2 [link](http://www.prodotgroup.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=108) is their download page, only a font and an antivirus is provided.  [link](http://www.prodotgroup.com/accessories-peripherals/peripherals/keyboard/kb-107m-ps2) Is the product page of this keyboard. Nothing there either. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry , after looking through it..your keyboard OEM seems not to provide any direct means to re-map their multimedia keys.. the furthest I've reached is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key) where most of the keyboard key re-purposing tools are listed.. || I'm aware that your original purpose in this question is to type special character.. may I know what is those characters?

Comment: why not just use Autohotkey to bind those keys? Here [is the keys list](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#multimedia)

Comment: sounds good. I was looking for some standalone software like something impoved over MKey. If nothing is found, I will use Autohotkey. Thanks.