# Want To Remap Windows Key + left Arrow to Home

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently switched back to Windows from macOS and my portable keyboard does not have a home or end key. I am wondering if there is a way to remap the Windows + Left Arrow to be Home key and Windows + Right Arrow to be the End key?

Comment: Home and End keys exist on all PC keyboards. Some require you to press along with Fn though. Mapping Win+Left to Home is a bad idea, since it's a system key for snapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use one of many 3d party utilities to remap keys.  See e.g.  [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key?noredirect=1&lq=1)
My favorite is [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) because it is like a real programming language, it is very popular and has good support.
Here is how you remap `win` + arrow keys. `#` stands for the `win` key.

```
#left::
    send {home}
return

#right::
    send {end}
return
```