# How to make the delete key act as backspace in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

In Windows 7, how to make the delete key act as the backspace key?

Comment: do you always want it to act this way or only in certain applications?  For instance, in Explorer, Delete, will delete the current file while backspace moves up the foldertree a lovel.  in notepad, Delete key removes character after cursor and backspapce the character before the cursor.  Which behavior do you wish to modify

Comment: Very similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/19526/reassigning-the-altgr-key-to-the-windows-key-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) to do all sorts of remapping in Windows 7.