# Remap Print Screen key under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, button-remapping, print-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reassigning the AltGr key to the Windows Key in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/19526/reassigning-the-altgr-key-to-the-windows-key-in-windows-7)

Is there a way to remap the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key under Windows 8 to some other key combination or to disable the print screen function?

Answer (score 2):

Try [KeyTweak](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml).  It'll allow you to remap that key's function.

Comment: that worked, thx